# Dynamics 365 SSRS | Print report Add margin top

Tags: reporting-services, dynamics-crm

I've weird behavior in Dynamics 365 report reviewer
when I try to print report from SSRS Report Reviewer directly it adds margin to the top, however in report properties I removed all margins.

Also when I export to Word then print , then this margin disappears.

How can I solve this.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Well, this is very common issue. It is not related with your report properties.
All I can recomment you here is to upload report to CRM and check if this issue is still present.

Also, the best way to print reports is to export them to PDF and print it from any PDF viewer, this extension is the best for report`s layout, to check the report from visual studio you can export it to PDF right from VS. Exported to PDF report will be the same both from CRM and Visual Studio